# Is the url property of a jQuery ajax request accessible in the done function?

Tags: jquery

I'm making multiple calls (in a loop) to $.ajax like so:

```
var getRequest = $.ajax({
url: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + etc,
type: "GET",
dataType: "json",
});
```

Can I get the url property (above) from the getRequest.done function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context of the `done` function is the jqXHR (a wrapper for the AJAX request). So you can access the `url` property using `this`

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + etc,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
}).done(function () { alert(this.url) })
```

Comment: Note: if 'context' property is set to 'this', it will not work.